# I am not sure whether I am being asked to calculate the variance or the irreducible error

Tags: variance, bias

The question:

> Suppose we randomly sample a training set D from some unknown
> distribution. For each training set D we sample, we train a regression
> model to predict $y$ from $x$. We repeat this 10 times resulting in 10
> trained models A new test sample $(x, y) = (3, 7)$ comes from the same
> distribution that generated the training sets. Recall that $y = f(x) +
> > e$, where $z$ has mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$. The predictions of
> the new test sample based on the 10 trained models are $6, 8, 9, 5,
> > 10, 5, 4, 8, 9, 3,$ Suppose the algorithm has a bias of O, based on
> the bias-variance theorem, what is an estimate of $\sigma^2$?

However, from my understanding sigma square is the irreducible noise. However, why is it labelled as variance here? Therefore I am confused as to whether i am supposed to calculate the noise or variance.

Answer (score 1):

Usually people will use $\sigma$ to denote standard deviation and $\sigma^2$ to denote variance, and $\epsilon$ to denote the irreducible error/noise. I think the question ask you to compute the variance $\sigma^2$, more about [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/calculate-the-bias-variance-trade-off/)